# Designing a Qt Creator's SideBar in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have created a class for making a `sidebar` just like in `Qt Creator` (one to the left). I am having no idea now to make it look exactly like the one in `Qt` creator as mine looks ugly!

The sidebar.h:

```
#ifndef _SIDEBAR_H_
#define _SIDEBAR_H_

#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPixmap>

#include <iostream>

class SideBar : public QWidget
{
public:
    SideBar(QWidget *parent=nullptr);

    void addIcon(const char *name);
    void addIcon(QString &name);

private:
    QVBoxLayout *_layout;
};

#endif // SIDEBAR_H
```

The sidebar.cpp

```
#include "sidebar.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QIcon>

SideBar::SideBar(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    _layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(_layout);
}

void SideBar::addIcon(const char *name)
{
    QString str(name);
    addIcon(str);
}

void SideBar::addIcon(QString &file)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);

    QPixmap pixmap(file);
    QIcon buttonIcon(pixmap);

    button->setIcon(buttonIcon);
    // button->setIconSize(pixmap.rect().size());

    _layout->addWidget(button);
}
```

This is one i want:

[image]

And this is one i got:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide two screenshots for comparison?

Comment: I have added screenshots!

Comment: Some ideas: you should start by using QToolButtons for side bar, adding the icons to them and set the autoRaise property in them. Then you could change the background color of the side bar to black.

Comment: Currently, i am using `QPushButton`. Will it make any difference?

Comment: Can you comment on making a `new tab` icon as in `chrome browser`? As you can see, i have created a new tab with a `+` button on it and made it disabled?

Comment: @abhiarora QToolButtons are generally better suited for this icon only buttons that perform actions. Also it includes the auto raise property that I talked about. More info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#details.

Comment: You should definitely explore QML to do this kind of stuff. But decide early if you want QML or not. Doing it properly requires a decent application model architecture that may not be necessary when doing it without QML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to use QAction to handle the clicks and icons, overwriting the methods paintEvent, mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent, leaveEvent, changing the colors regarding the state in which the widget is.

**sidebar.h**

```
#ifndef SIDEBAR_H
#define SIDEBAR_H

#include <QAction>
#include <QWidget>

class SideBar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SideBar(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void addAction(QAction *action);
    QAction *addAction(const QString &text, const QIcon &icon = QIcon());
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent * event);

    QAction *actionAt(const QPoint &at);
private:
    QList<QAction *> mActions;

    QAction *mCheckedAction;
    QAction *mOverAction;
};

#endif // SIDEBAR_H
```

**sidebar.cpp**

```
#include "sidebar.h"

#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>

#define action_height 90


SideBar::SideBar(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), mCheckedAction(NULL), mOverAction(NULL)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}


void SideBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter p(this);

    QFont fontText(p.font());
    fontText.setFamily("Helvetica Neue");
    p.setFont(fontText);

    int action_y = 0;
    p.fillRect(rect(), QColor(100, 100, 100));
    for(auto action: mActions)
    {

        QRect actionRect(0, action_y, event->rect().width(), action_height);

        if(action->isChecked())
        {
            p.fillRect(actionRect, QColor(35, 35, 35));
        }

        if(action == mOverAction){
            p.fillRect(actionRect, QColor(150, 150, 150));
        }

        p.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255));
        QSize size = p.fontMetrics().size(Qt::TextSingleLine, action->text());
        QRect actionTextRect(QPoint(actionRect.width()/2 - size.width()/2, actionRect.bottom()-size.height()-5), size);
        p.drawText(actionTextRect, Qt::AlignCenter, action->text());

        QRect actionIconRect(0, action_y + 10, actionRect.width(), actionRect.height()-2*actionTextRect.height()-10);
        QIcon  actionIcon(action->icon());
        actionIcon.paint(&p, actionIconRect);

        action_y += actionRect.height();
    }

}

QSize SideBar::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return action_height*QSize(1, mActions.size());
}

void SideBar::addAction(QAction *action)
{
    mActions.push_back(action);
    action->setCheckable(true);
    update();
}

QAction *SideBar::addAction(const QString &text, const QIcon &icon)
{
    QAction *action = new QAction(icon, text, this);
    action->setCheckable(true);
    mActions.push_back(action);
    update();
    return action;
}

void SideBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QAction* tempAction = actionAt(event->pos());
    if(tempAction == NULL || tempAction->isChecked())
        return;
    qDebug()<<"clicked";
    if(mCheckedAction)
        mCheckedAction->setChecked(false);
    if(mOverAction == tempAction)
        mOverAction = NULL;
    mCheckedAction = tempAction;
    tempAction->setChecked(true);
    update();
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}


void SideBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QAction* tempAction = actionAt(event->pos());
    if(tempAction == NULL){
        mOverAction = NULL;
        update();
        return;
    }
    if(tempAction->isChecked() || mOverAction == tempAction)
        return;
    mOverAction = tempAction;
    update();
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void SideBar::leaveEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    mOverAction = NULL;
    update();
    QWidget::leaveEvent(event);
}

QAction* SideBar::actionAt(const QPoint &at)
{
    int action_y = 0;
    for(auto action: mActions)
    {
        QRect actionRect(0, action_y, rect().width(), action_height);
        if(actionRect.contains(at))
            return action;
        action_y += actionRect.height();
    }
    return NULL;
}

#undef action_height
```

The sample code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/others/SideBar).

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: link to sample code is broken. Btw is there any pyqt version of the sample code.

Comment: @azzamsa A few months ago I modified the structure of my repository so some links were broken, thanks for letting me know :-) and I corrected the link.

Comment: @azzamsa Later I will publish a version in PyQt5.